# Avian infrasonic navigation cues

Tags: bird

There is scattered information on avian infrasonic navigation cues - mostly having to do with flight decision responses driven by barometric conditions. I am interested in whether infrasonic noise generated by wind turbines might interfere with these cues.

Comment: It might be helpful to refine your main question. Please be specific and include references to what information you've already found.

Answer (score 2):

If the assumption is that birds are able to monitor the barometric pressure and especially changes to barometric pressure, we can perhaps address the question by asking a more specific question: How large fluctuations in ambient pressure can infrasound from a wind turbine create?
Assume a very loud turbine with a source level of 94 dB re 20 µPa, measured as the maximum zero-to-peak amplitude. This equals a pressure fluctuation of 1 Pa around the ambient pressure. If the ambient pressure is 1000 hPa, which is the same as 100,000 Pa, we see that the fluctuations caused by the turbine is minuscule (0.001%), even very close to the turbine and would be even less further away from the turbine. From this it seems very unlikely that the amplitude modulation in ambient pressure caused by the wind turbine would be able to interfere with any ability of birds to sense the absolute ambient pressure or changes in the pressure over periods of minutes to hours, as this would require an exceptionally high resolution of the sensory organ.